# Uploading Program to Arduino Using FTDI Cable or Programmer

Tags: upload, arduino

I would like detailed instructions on how to go about uploading a program onto an Arduino using an FTDI cable/programmer. I'm just not quite sure what parts to order and how to go about doing it.

Do I require both the FTDI cable as well as a breakout board? Or just one or the other? How exactly does it physically connect to the Arduino/computer?

Comment: Not programming-related - try http://electronics.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's detailed instructions if you scroll down to the end of this tutorial by using an AVR programmer:

http://itp.nyu.edu/physcomp/Tutorials/ArduinoBreadboard